# C++ values not reading in while loop switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

All functions have be declared public in my .header file
this is my  code:

```
void menu
{
int option = 0;
  //cout menu here//
  //getting user input to enter their option of menu
  cin>>option;
  menuChoice(option);
}

void menuChoice(int option)
{


  int kiv = 0; 
 const int size = 50;
    while(option) //option just an int to get input from a menu
    {
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: {
                       while(kiv<size)
                        {
                          //codes here to read user inputs then entry increment
                           ++kiv;
                         }
                        //cout<<kiv<<endl; // doesn't work here too , it displays nothing
                     }break;
             case2:{
                       cout<<kiv<<endl; // displays 0
                    }break;
         }
    }
}
```

i have declared the kiv on top , then increment it in the while loop , however the value stays in the while(option) loop so when i go to case 2 , it suppose to print out the incremented value , but it display 0 , am i going in the correct direction?

Comment: Please write full code, with initialization of option and with getting user input

Comment: so you go to case 2 on second round?

Comment: @Pavel check edit the code is too long for everything so i just wrote the flow of it here.

Comment: @Pragun i tried entering case 1 many times after that going to case 2 , it still displays 0

Answer (score 0):

This may be the one you looking for

```
    int kiv = 0;
    const int size = 50;
    void menuChoice(int option);
    void getOption()
    {
        int option = 0;
        cin >> option;
        menuChoice(option);
    }
    void menuChoice(int option)
    {

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            while (kiv < size) {
                //codes here to read user inputs then entry increment
                ++kiv;
            }
            //cout<<kiv<<endl; // doesn't work here too , it displays nothing
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << kiv << endl; // displays 0
            break;
        }
        getOption();
    }
    void menu()
    {
        //cout menu here//
        //getting user input to enter their option of menu
        getOption();

    }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But whats the problem with my loop? i know global declaration might solve the problem , however the value stays in the loop , i should be able to retrieve it , but what went wrong? and sorry i forgot to mention my function s are being declared public in my class .header file

Comment: menuChoice first whileloop ,it never go out of loop.The menuChoice calling thread never return from this function beacuse of this loop.& it not accepting any new input ,thisloop is not required.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your example, but I am guessing that each time you process a menuChoice you enter that function, and as a result you re-initialised kiv back to 0 each time.

If that is the case, you probably need to change the type of kiv to

```
static int kiv = 0;
```

This will cause kiv to retain its value between invocations.